# Python BeautifulSoup Error In Parsing HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm having a problem with BeautifulSoup parsing certain information from [here](http://www.whatismyipaddress.com).  After I grab the html code with the module **Mechanize** I'm trying to focus my wanted end results on this little snippet of html:

```
    <table style="padding-top:10px;">
        <tr><th>ISP:</th><td>Brighthouse Networks</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Services:</th><td><a href="/ip-services">None Detected</a></td></tr>
        <tr><th>City:</th><td>Miami</td></tr>
        <th>Region:</th><td>Florida</td>
        <tr><th>Country:</th><td>United States</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Now I want my end results to be as such:

```
    ISP: Brighthouse Networks
    Services: None Detected
    City: Miami
    Region: Florida
    Country: United States
```

My parsing section of my script I wrote is:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.findall('table',{'style':'padding-top:10px;'})
    for t in table:
        print t.text
```

However, this does not yield the results I wanted which I listed above.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What results does your script yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<table style="padding-top:10px;">
    <tr><th>ISP:</th><td>Brighthouse Networks</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Services:</th><td><a href="/ip-services">None Detected</a></td></tr>
    <tr><th>City:</th><td>Miami</td></tr>
    <th>Region:</th><td>Florida</td>
    <tr><th>Country:</th><td>United States</td></tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.findAll('table', {"style":"padding-top:10px;"})[0]

trs = table('tr')
for tr in trs:
    print tr.th.text,
    print tr.td.text

#and this for the 'Region'
print table("th")[3].text,
print table("td")[3].text
```

Output:

```
ISP: Brighthouse Networks
Services: None Detected
City: Miami
Country: United States
Region: Florida
```

Comment: You don't contemplate the  `<th>Region:</th><td>Florida</td>` in your answer

Comment: You have syntax error from `BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` in wrong, see edit

Comment: Yes, you are right... I rejected the edit by mistake... http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4

Answer (score 1):

```
table = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'style':'padding-top:10px;'})
```

should do the trick.

[find_all()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) has the following signature:

`find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, limit, **kwargs)`

If you pass attribute as second argument find_all expects it to be a string and not a dictionary. If you want to pass a dictionary of attributes to find_all you should do this by passing it as [attrs keyword argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).